# QGIS swaps(?) attribute tables of PostGIS layers

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a QGIS project (2.18.14 Win10), last saved yesterday, with several PostGIS layers. As I opened the project today the PostGIS layers did not display on the map (but appear in the Layers Panel). The layers' properties (source, etc.) are correct, but their attribute tables are those of other PostGIS layers. It's as if QGIS somehow mixed up the attribute tables.

Other layers (shapefiles) in the same project display correctly.

I have not touched the database. An ArcMap document saved at the same time and accessing the same PostGIS layers shows no issues.

Any ideas on what might be going on and how to fix this?

Comment: How are you accessing PostGIS through ArcMap? Is it possible a 'version' was created from the Arc-GUI and messing up how the real data is being viewed from QGIS?

Comment: Thank you. It is very possible. I am somewhat new to PostGIS. I will look into this and will report back here.

Comment: I am accessing PostGIS from ArcMap through ArcMap's native Database Connections, in (what I believe to be) read-only mode. No ArcGIS Server.

To test whether ArcMap might be breaking my QGIS projects I readded one of the PostGIS layers to QGIS, saved, closed. Then started a new ArcMap document, added the same layer, saved, closed. Reopened the QGIS project, everything works fine.

I'll continue to explore.